# creating array of threads on window in a loop and wait statement

Tags: multithreading

Is this correct ? I want to create stageList.size() threads which execute startHelper function but I don't know how to make a Linux `waitid()` on window.

```
HANDLE *threads =  new HANDLE[stageList.size()];
DWORD *thId =  new DWORD[stageList.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < stageList.size(); i++) {
       threads[i]=CreateThread(NULL, 0, startHelper, (LPVOID) stageList.at(i),0,&thId[i]);
      if ( threads[i]== NULL) {
      printf("CreateThread failed: %d\n",GetLastError());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

WaitForMultipleObjects(stageList.size(),threads, true, INFINITE);